# How to upload and register a model to Databricks from Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, databricks, mlflow, large-language-model

I fine-tuned an LLM in Vertex AI, but I would like to register and load the model into Databricks so I can run inference from there. Currently I have these files in a GCS bucket:

```
added_tokens.json
config.json
generation_config.json
merges.txt
pytorch_model.bin
special_tokens_map.json
tokenizer_config.json
training_args.bin
vocab.json
```

Going off of this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/en/mlflow/models.html) I can save a model locally to DBFS, but it doesn't mention which file(s) I need to upload. After I upload them, I assume I can then register the model in the model registry using this code:

```
mlflow.register_model("runs:/{run_id}/{model-path}", "{registered-model-name}")
```

Am I going about this correctly? I saw the two other questions about this but they didn't quite answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right way.

I'd upload all the files that you have here into a folder in DBFS then try to load the model in a Databricks notebook.

```
class Net(nn.Module):
// Your Model for which you want to load parameters 

model = Net()
torch.optim.SGD(lr=0.001) #According to your own Configuration.
checkpoint = torch.load(pytorch_model)
model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
optimizer.load_state_dict(checkpoint['opt'])
```

Once that's done, use [mlflow.pytorch.log()](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pytorch.html) to save your model to MLFlow experiments. Then you can use `mlflow.register()` or pass the argument `registered_model_name` when you log the model to register it directly.

You might need to create an MLFlow custom class depending on how complex your model is ([MLFlow Pyfunc](https://medium.com/@pennyqxr/how-save-and-load-fasttext-model-in-mlflow-format-37e4d6017bf0)), which is often the case for LLM as they need additional components to work. You'll then need to specify your custom way to override the functions `load_context` (to load your model) and `predict`(how to predict with your model). There's a cool example in the article up there!

Comment: got it, thanks Julie! Do you know if I can set it up so the model will also accept generation hyperparameters, like temperature and max_new_tokens?